# Python: how to copy files in /bin/ folder

Tags: python, copy, system-administration

I'd like to place a special file in the /usr/bin folder of Ubuntu. Basically I'm trying to write a setup file in python which would do the job.

But administrative privileges are needed to fulfill the job, how to provide my setup with these privileges (provided that I have the password and can use it in my program)?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5191878/929437

Comment: don't write to `/usr/bin`, use `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just escalate the privileges of alredy running script (well, unless you use some local exploit).

The best way to go is to follow @Lattyware's advice and just force user to run the script with root priveleges (via `sudo` or by any other means). This is pretty common practice for installers.

However, if you REALLY need to escalate privileges midway (I can't imagine why), you can do something like:

```
import os
cpstr = 'echo %(pass)s | sudo -S cp "%(from)s" "%(to)s"'
os.system(cpstr % {'pass':'userpassword', 'from':'./build/bin/myapp', 'to':'/bin/myapp'})
```

Comment: To be fair, there are sometimes good reasons to escalate privileges mid-execution. For example, `yaourt`, a package manager for Arch Linux allows the user to build packages from the AUR - however, making a package as root is dangerous (as the scripts could in theory do anything), so it's best to make the package with lower permissions, then get root privileges to install the package.

Comment: @Lattyware I see your point, however I think it is usually better to _lower_ privileges when necessary, rather then escalate them: it's easier (therefore, usually safer) to implement (`setuid`/`seteuid`) and the user is aware that what he is going to execute will affect the entire system.

Comment: You make a good point, just saying what I've seen in the wild.

Comment: You can also use $HOME/.local/bin in the user's space as this is in the default path for bash at least.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the program with escalated privileges. Under Ubuntu, this is normally done with the `sudo` command, which will prompt the user for their password.