# how to write the sudo vbetool dpms off command in python file?

Tags: python

I am new in python, i just open .py file and write this command inside the file "sudo vbetool dpms off". But while run the file, it shows invalid syntax. How to write this command to python file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard library [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess
passwd='mypassword'
subprocess.call('echo %s|sudo -S vbetool dpms off' % passwd, shell=True)
```

Comment: but it ask sudo password. i need to run this code without password. if it works like that, it is very useful to me. Please provide me the solution

Comment: it seems duplicated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191878/change-to-sudo-user-within-a-python-script

Comment: @Viswa: You should learn to accept and vote on answers that has been helpful to you :)

Comment: Its work properly, but i am not suppose to defined my password in script. Instead of that,if system automatically retrieved password means its very convenient to me. Is there any chance to do like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo -S` which is used to read password from stdin rather than terminal.Store it in a file,say passwd and then do:

```
import os
os.system("sudo -S vbetool dpms off < passwd")
```

Comment: where is stdin located. i think u saying i need to give the password in that file right.

Comment: the password must be saved in a file,which is `passwd` as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or

You could use [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/) library which is commonly used to automate programs that require user inputs.

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('sudo vbetool dpms off')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline(password)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=None)
output_data =  child.before
```

Here, you just provide the matching prompt that you are expecting and then you send the password. After that you can collect the output and process it.

This is more generic and is useful when you have programs that does not accept piping of password.

you can install this module with

```
easy_install pexpect
or
pip install pexpect
```