# How to write a subprocess.Popen terminal execution

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, terminate

I want to kill a process on a remote server with another user, who creted the process via python with the `subprocess.Popen` command. But there is something I must be doing wrong because nothing happens when I run:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['sudo','kill','-9',str(pid)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In terminal `sudo kill -9 pid` works fine.

Comment: Do you get any error? How are you passing the `sudo` password?

Comment: try `os.system('sudo kill -9 pid')`

Comment: @heemayl No error, but you are right I have somehow pass the sudo password' But how?

Comment: @Legorooj Tried this one too, nothing happens, I think heemayl is right I need to pass the sudo password somehow

Comment: one may configure to run sudo without password via /etc/sudoers

Comment: It does appear that way. Look at this question - it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191878/change-to-sudo-user-within-a-python-script

Comment: @Sav Varlor probably doesn't want passwordless sudo as a default on their machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got the answer thanks to the comment by Legorooj.

```
from subprocess import call
import os
command = 'kill -9 '+str(pid)
#p = os.system('echo {}|sudo -S {}'.format(password, command))
call('echo {} | sudo -S {}'.format(password, command), shell=True)
```

Comment: Good to know that I helped! Btw you should select this as the correct answer, that way it'll show up as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer works. A slightly more formal way of doing this would be something like

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def kill(pid, passwd):
    pipe = Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'kill', '-9', str(pid)], 
                 stdout=PIPE, 
                 stdin=PIPE, 
                 stderr=PIPE)
    pipe.stdin.write(bytes(passwd + '\n', encoding='utf-8'))
    pipe.stdin.flush()
    # at this point, the process is killed, return output and errors
    return (str(pipe.stdout.read()), str(pipe.stderr.read()))
```

If I were writing this for a production system, I would add some exception handling, so treat this as a proof of concept.

Comment: Definitely an improvement - much safer from a security point of view.