# change user privilege within python

Tags: python, sudo

I am writing a program that I need to check if user is root (if it is not allow user to input password to get sudo) either way the program will continue but will have less features if it's not root.
I tried [Change to sudo user within a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191878/change-to-sudo-user-within-a-python-script)

```
spawn sudo
expect {
    "Password:" {
        send "password"
    }
}
```

my python script

```
import os
import subprocess
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    #function to allow user to change to sudo
    subprocess.call(['tclsh', 'sudo.tcl'])
```

I got the following error `invalid command name "spawn"
    while executing
"spawn sudo"
    (file "sudo.tcl" line 1)`

My question is how to allow user to gain root within the script?

Comment: Did you try the other answer in the linked question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9527553/6486738

Comment: @TedKleinBergman it works but this allows to try 3 times, I only want one time try

Comment: Do you mean that you only want the user to be able to try the password 3 times? In that case, you have a different question than the one you posted. I'd suggest you edit in all the requirements into the question.